# Añadir nueva acción en 'Acciones Agrupadas' de prestashop

Tags: controller, prestashop1.7

En prestashop cuando se crea un `AdminController` se crea una tabla con todos los registros, y sus respectivos filtros. Necesito obtener los registros que se muestran en esa tabla pero filtrados. Es decir, filtro por alguna columna y en la tabla se actualizan las filas y me muestra todas aquellas que cumplan el filtro.

¿Como puedo obtener todos esos datos filtrados, en forma de array, para tratarlos en otro método?

Se me ocurre, que abajo de la tabla, en 'Acciones agrupadas' vienen algunas acciones que aplica a todo lo seleccionado y/o filtrado. ¿Es posible añadir una nueva acción a este `dropdown`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería información sobre algún método o campo que sirva para editar estas acciones o algo similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Dentro del controlador, en el constructor. Basta con añadir:

```
    $this->bulk_actions = array(
        'report' => array(
            'text' => $this->l('Descargar informe')
        )
    );
```

Donde `report` es el nombre que recibirá la función enlazada.

Y creamos el siguiente metodo, que se ejecutara al hacer click en la nueva acción:

```
protected function processBulkReport()
{
   // Con $this->boxes recogemos todo el array de elementos seleccionados.
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]